# How add UINavigationBar in Interface Builder with the same effect of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When i create a new UINavigationController, the navigation bar and the status bar are one, and since iOS 7 both have a translucent effect like this:

[image]

so both status bar and navigation bar are translucent, and attached, instead if i add a simple UINavigationBar in Interface Builder, the result is this:

[image]

so the navigation bar is over the status bar, so my question is how i can achieve the same result adding it on interface builder? or also programmatically, but without using UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Y" position of the navigation bar. Did you placed it at 20 or 0. I guess mistakenly you might have placed at 0. So check once in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layout constraint for the top space of the navigation bar to be 0 points to the Top Layout Guide